# REST API Best Practices

Tags: rest

We are developing a REST API and we're allowing all four of the standard verbs.  In the case of an POST/PUT, the API client will need to modify values on certain fields.  Take the psuedo example:

```
class Employee {
  long Id;
  long DepartmentId; // should i expose this?
  string Department; // or should i expose this?
}
```

- The use-case here is that a client will POST a new employee and fill out all fields.
- There is a table of departments in our database behind the API
- The client will need to get a list of valid departments to send
- The client can make an API call to get the list of departments as such:

> {
>               "department_id": "1", 
>               "department": "Technology"
>           },
>  
>           {
>               "department_id": "2", 
>               "department": "Human Resources"
>           }

The client the can include one of the above valid departments. My question is, should a POST/PUT request include the department id or the name? The id seems easier to validate against but less "friendly" to the client.  In either case we can properly validate against our reference table, but I'm wondering what the best practice is.

Comment: Will the client be some form of selection, like a dropdown box for the department?  I think there should be a class `Department`.

Comment: I can make a department class, but that still doesn't really solve my issue.  I'm assuming the API has no front end and the client has to make requests to get all reference data ahead of time.

Comment: API Consumers should send you the ID *and* the full-blown object. Easier for them (new object(), fill props, send stuff) and for you (grab object, use it as-is after validating the contents, little effort). Never, *ever* use names to associate data.

Comment: While it is often not the most pragmatic solution, the best practice from a pure RESTful point of view is to use the URI as the indentifier while applying the HATEAOS principle...

Answer (score 1):

It should use the ID. The API consumer must be capable of understanding references. In this case, it needs to understand that it refers to one specific department. To do so, the client might have to query the list of available departments first, but that shouldn't worry you as long as you do expose such an endpoint.

Using the department name would make the department name a unique key, which changes the semantics quite severely. Also, you might need to index the department name to implement this efficiently, which is another somewhat heavy downside of using the name.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Employee {
  long Id;
  Department Dept;
}
```

or

```
class Employee {
      long Id;
      long DepartmentId;
    }

    class Department{
      long DepartmentId; 
      string DepartmentName; 
    }
```

This is cleaner for the class structure.  As for the client, they will need a Selection control for selecting the department - you can't expect them to know the ID or get the name correct.  I have used a `AutoComplete` box for large selections or a `dropdown` box for a small list.

To answer the question on what to send back `from` the client, I would send back the `ID`.

Comment: Why would the Employee contain a department? Why is Employee's primary key simply `Id`, but Department's primary key is `DepartmentId`?

Comment: What is there is no front end for the API? The client would need to ahead of time get a list of departments, which is fine, it's just a question of what makes more sense for them to pass back?

Comment: @mnemosyn, I didn't come up with the naming convention, and it's a psuedo example.  The Employee needs a reference to the Department, either having a Department object or the PK, DepartmentId.  I was just illustrating that the Employee should not have department info.

Comment: @christiandev: ah, ok... depends on how one reads that 'class'... In a json endpoint, one might want to expose the de-normalized department name

Comment: @AdamLevitt, since the client is getting a list of departments, then you should pass back the ID IMO.

Comment: @Adam: The Id, because the name might have changed in the mean time. Ids are a primary key: They are unique and they can't be edited, unlike names.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally better practice to have URIs that convey meaning. For example

```
www.mylocalpaper.com/news/local/politics/2013_town_budget_approved
```

is better than

```
www.mylocalpaper.com/sections/12/subsection/13/article/45
```

since Section 12 Subsection 13 Article 45 doesn't mean anything to anyone outside of the web server code. Obviously make sure that the URL for each department is unique (the U in URL).

You should also return the full URL to the client for the department, not just a short name, and use that URL to add a user to that department. So return

```
{ "add_employee_url": "/departments/tech/employees/", "name": "Technology" },
{ "add_employee_url": "/departments/hr/employees/", "name": "Human Resources" }
```

Then the client simply posts the employee details to the URL that matches the selection. The client user selects "Technology" and the client posts to `/departments/tech/employees/`.

If the URL for the department changes (say `tech` becomes `technology` down the line) the client won't care because it is getting the full URL for the action.

Comment: What if the Employee object has many fields like this on it? Not just the department...

Comment: The information for the new employee should be in the body of the request, for example in JSON or XML or whatever format. POSTing this data to /departments/tech/employees basically says here is a new employee resource please add this new employee to this department using this information (eg name, age, salary etc). You do this if the server decides the final URL, say it generates a new ID for the user based on an auto increment number in the DB. The server should then return the URL it created to the client, eg /departments/tech/employees/13434.

Comment: If the client decides the URL, say for example the URL for the employee resource should be her staff number which is already known, then the client can simply PUT the data to that URL (eg PUT /department/tech/employees/AB3423). The server should recognize that this employee isn't actually in the system yet and create a new database record based on the data, but this creation should be hidden from the client. You do this if the client determines the final URL.